# In wurst, how to delete an exchange in an activity and add a new exchange

Tags: brightway

I created a new activity "alu_in_no" as the following code:

```
alu_in_eu = w.get_one(data, w.equals('location','IAI Area, EU27 & EFTA'), w.contains("name", "aluminium production, primary, liquid, prebake"))
alu_in_no = w.transformations.geo.copy_to_new_location(alu_in_eu, 'NO')
data.append(alu_in_no)
w.transformations.geo.relink_technosphere_exchanges(
    alu_in_no,
    data,
    contained=False
)
```

The new activity has the following exchange:

```
{'amount': 14.65,
 'loc': 14.65,
 'location': 'IAI Area, EU27 & EFTA',
 'name': 'market for electricity, medium voltage, aluminium industry',
 'pedigree': {'completeness': 1,
  'further technological correlation': 1,
  'geographical correlation': 1,
  'reliability': 1,
  'temporal correlation': 3}
```

I want to delete this exchange in this activity and replace a new one, for example:

```
 {'amount': 1.0,
   'loc': 1.0,
   'location': 'NO',
   'name': 'market for electricity, medium voltage',
   'product': 'electricity, medium voltage',
   'production volume': 131798608305.945,
   'type': 'production',
   'uncertainty type': 0,
   'unit': 'kilowatt hour'}
```

In other word, I want to unlink the previous activity and link another activity? I believe there must be some functions in wurst can do it but I cannot find.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The list of exchanges is a normal list, so you can delete the exchange the same way you would delete from any other list, e.g. `del my_list[some_index` or `my_list = [x for x in my_list if some_condition_on_x(x)]`.

You would need to relink your new exchange, but you already know how to do this: `relink_technosphere_exchanges`. You can run it more than once, it won't change exchanges which are linked already.

Comment: Hello Chris, thank you so much for your help. When I added the new exchanges as above, and then extract database like  `w.brightway.write_database.write_brightway2_database(data, 'Newdatabase0131')`, but it returns `Multiple production exchanges found`. What's wrong with that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In theory, nothing, though multioutput processes can cause [matrix problems](https://chris.mutel.org/multioutput.html). The easiest way to avoid this is to call every product *not* the reference product an input, and flip the sign. The assumption that each activity has one reference product is hard-coded in wurst; please [file an issue](https://github.com/IndEcol/wurst/issues/new) if you think this is a big problem.

Comment: Sorry I didn't catch it, I understand it's a matrix problem, but how to call every product an input? Could you explain more specifically? Thanks!